# Oracle SQL - Combine two rows based on the date

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to combine two rows based on the date into one row.  Here is the source table

| MDATE | LID | VALUE1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-SEP-21 | 1 | 1231 |
| 01-SEP-21 | 2 | 2342 |
| 02-SEP-21 | 1 | 4561 |
| 02-SEP-21 | 2 | 6782 |
| 03-SEP-21 | 1 | 8901 |
| 03-SEP-21 | 2 | 9992 |

And I am expecting result as:

| MDATE | LID | VALUE1 | MDATE | LID | VALUE1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01-SEP-21 | 1 | 1231 | 01-SEP-21 | 2 | 2342 |
| 02-SEP-21 | 1 | 4561 | 02-SEP-21 | 2 | 6782 |
| 03-SEP-21 | 1 | 8901 | 03-SEP-21 | 2 | 9992 |

I can use two CTEs to get the desired result.  However, is there any other way w/o using CTE?

Code in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=60d7dc974d240a8899b2e8d514a79505)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select mdate,
       max(case when lid = 1 then value end) as value1,
       max(case when lid = 2 then value end) as value2
from t
group by mdate;
```

I see no reason to repeat the `mdate` column, nor to have the `lid` columns that contain a single value.

But, if you really wanted that, you could use:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.mdate = t2.mdate and t1.lid = 1 and t2.lid = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [PIVOT query](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1).

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT mdate, lid, value1 FROM t
)
PIVOT (
    SUM(value1)
    for lid IN (1, 2)
)
ORDER BY mdate
```

It yields the lid # as column name

```
MDATE       1       2
01-SEP-21   1231    2342
02-SEP-21   4561    6782
03-SEP-21   8901    9992
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7b71cb61b0f454acc4af25c14efb4b71)